# tcp/ip - trigger action or event after period of no network activity on certain port(s)

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, routing

Is it possible, perhaps using iptables or one of the wrappers/frontends to iptables, to trigger an action or run a script after a certain period of time has elapsed with no network activity on a certain incoming tcp or udp port? To put it as simply as possible, I'm trying to set up a host that will suspend/hibernate itself, shut itself off, shut off certain services or just generally perform some kind action if certain servers running on it go idle. However, the host will need to run arbitrary server applications listening on arbitrary ports, so I can't configure this at the application level. I'm thinking along the lines of how the Heroku and Google App Engine platforms will stop applications if they go idle long enough, but with arbitrary server applications rather than just a web server.

Comment: It looks like this thread has some useful advice: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=866006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. I can use the `LOG` target to an iptables rule in combination with `--log-prefix` and use a script running out of cron to grep for the log prefix out of syslog/dmesg to find the most recent packet that matched the iptables rule and then run arbitrary commands.